# NgbPopover with Fullcalendar angular 5

Tags: angular5, popover, ng-bootstrap

I'm having trouble using the NgbPopover component along with fullcalendar.
In the FullCalendar eventRender I'm inserting the required attributes for ngbPopover, but it does not execute.

```
eventRender(dados) {
        let title = dados.event.title
        let description = dados.event.description
        let el = dados.element[0]
        el.setAttributeNS(null, "popoverTitle", title)
        el.setAttributeNS(null, "ngbPopover", description != undefined ? description : "" ) 
        el.setAttributeNS(null, "triggers", "mouseenter:mouseleave")
    }
```

I need a way to run Popover after doing the inserts of the attributes in html.

When I put the code straight into the html without going through the eventRender it works.

Comment: Hi... how did you solve this issue. Currently I am facing the same.

Comment: I did not find a solution, I changed it to open it in a modal when I click on the event